# Overriding ProductController action doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, product, overrides, controllers

I have declare my module on app/ etc/ module

```
<ML_CanonicalRedirect>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
    </ML_CanonicalRedirect>
```

Then add on app\code\local\ML\CanonicalRedirect my etc and controllers folder

in etc i've got my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ML_CanonicalRedirect>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </ML_CanonicalRedirect>
    </modules>
 <frontend> 
        <routers> 
          <catalog> 
             <args> 
             <modules> 
                <ML_CanonicalRedirect before="Mage_Catalog">ML_CanonicalRedirect</ML_CanonicalRedirect>
             </modules> 
             </args> 
         </catalog> 
       </routers> 
   </frontend>
</config>
```

in controllers i've got ProductControllers.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php';
class ML_CanonicalRedirect_ProductController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController {
    public function viewAction()
    {  header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    exit;
}
}
```

But magento load anyway the core class. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change module declaratioan file (ML_CanonicalRedirect.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ML_CanonicalRedirect>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ML_CanonicalRedirect>
    </modules>
<config>
```

Edit:

Change file name form `ProductControllers.php` to `ProductController.php`.

Comment: it is the same! I didn't copy all tag just beacause I use ML_ALL so I have other declaration! But the module it seen by magento. If I go to Advance I can see it!

Comment: Do you see anything in error log files? Error logs are turned on?

Comment: I eddited my answer. You have wrong filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for `ProductController.php`

```
<?php 
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Catalog').DS.'ProductController.php');
class ML_CanonicalRedirect_ProductController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController {
    public function viewAction()
    {  
       header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
       exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! nothing change